# How do I fire only one event at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".timeSeenInput").on("focusout keypress",function(event){
        alert($(this).attr("id"))
    })
```

I need to detect when the user tabs away from an input box or when pressing away from it.
the code above fires twice for when I press a key. how do I make it either fire for either tab or focusout but not both?

Comment: `blur` is it what you need?

Comment: Do you really want it for every `keypress`? This will fire when the user types in the input.

Comment: @Jai Why blur? Same behaviour than focusout except not bubbling

Comment: @Jai how, in fact i didn't saw you were asking a question '?'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could debounce it a little:

http://jsfiddle.net/wVbeB/

```
(function () {
    var timeout;
    $(".timeSeenInput").on("focusout keypress", function (event) {
        if (!timeout) {
            var self = this;
            timeout = setTimeout(function () {
                console.log(self.id);
                timeout = null;
            }, 0);
        }

    })
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Tabbing out is produced by both events. You can flag your tabbing out event and not handle the blur:

```
var handleBlur = true;
$(".timeSeenInput").on("focusout keypress",function(event) {
    if (event.type === 'keypress' && event.keyCode === TAB) {
        alert($(this).attr("id"));
        handleBlur = false;
        return;
    } else if (event.type === 'blur' && handleBlur) {
        // Handle blur
    }
    handleBlur = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the `blur` event is for.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DPh6P/

```
$(".timeSeenInput").on("blur", function (event) {
    alert($(this).attr("id"))
})
```

Comment: And if OP wants to fired event on keypress too?

Comment: @roasted "I need to detect when the user tabs away from an input box or when pressing away from it". It sounds to me like he wants to detect when the user leaves the input.

Comment: @MattHarrison as i understood OP's issue, he didn't want to fired both events when pressing TAB key, but i should admit i cannot see really any reason to use then both events in this case, only keypress event should be enough or only blur.

Answer (score 0):

This will only fire when `tab key` is pressed and `focusout` is happened:

```
$(".timeSeenInput").on("focusout keydown", function (e) {
   var kc = e.which || e.keyCode;
   if (kc === 9) {
      alert('focusout with tab only');
   }
});
```